# Running a game server from a VM

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, games, steam

I am fairly new to Linux and Ubuntu in general, but for a learning project, I am trying to set up a game server (TF2 using SteamCMD) on a Ubuntu VM through Virtual Box...

I have been able to setup the server and run it, but I cannot connect to it. I'm assuming this has to do with then network configuration and/or port forwarding. The game server is not showing up in the LAN either. My host is a windows machine. The game server console reports an IP address for the server, but I cannot connect.

I apologize if this is somewhat broad, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You will want to check the network settings in VirtualBox and ensure the network is “bridged” and running in “promiscuous mode”.

Comment: Ok, I have the network as bridged, but promiscuous mode was 'deny', I set it to all as well. I can see the server in my LAN server browser, which is good. However, the IP address that displays in the server browser is my VM's internal IP address, but the public address displayed in the server console on start up is different. The public ip display in the console server DOES match my public ip when using a 'whatsmyip' tool on my host machine... what IP would I give to someone externally to connect? Thanks.

Comment: How externally is external? Same network, but different computer? Or outside the network and over the Internet? 

Comment: outside the network and over the internet.

Comment: To have the server accessible over the internet: (1) your ISP will need to not block the ports you’re using (2) the network router will need to forward traffic on specific ports to the VM (3) the VM will need to be assigned a static IP, either through DHCP addressing or manually. Items (1) and (2) are outside the scope of this site, though 